# Constant water running from hot water heater

Tags: water-heater

A few days ago I started hearing water running from washing machine drain. After looking it is the copper pipe running from the hot water heater. There is no other leaks, no loss in pressure or temperature. What could this be?

Comment: It could be your pressure relief valve. Can you post a picture of where the water's running from?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a continuous “on demand” water loop.

We install a copper pipe loop throughout the house in large houses and pump hot water throughout the loop 24/7. Then we tie all sinks, tubs, etc. into this loop for instantaneous hot water. It eliminates the need for waiting for hot water to flow from the water heater to a sink at the far end of a house.

However, if you have this it should not leak. It’s a closed system. If it’s leaking you must have an extremely high heating bill.

Answer (score 0):

Is this from one of the two pipes on top of the water heater that go to the rest of the house? That would be "just a leak" - a waste of water and the harbinger of a flood (when the pipe bursts).

Or is this a pipe attached to the top or side of the water heater that is open on the other end? That one is the relief valve, and water flowing through it is an indication that the water heater is having some serious problems, and you need either repair or, if the water heater is old, replacement.

Comment: Sometimes the relief valve is ALSO on top...and the "pipe running to the washing machine drain" sounds rather like pressure relief plumbing.

Comment: The "pipe running to the washing machine drain" could also be a primer for the trap, perhaps from before there was a washer. We really need OP's pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Is your water hotter then normal, if so lower the temperature setting a little and check in a few hours after using some hot water if it has stopped. If not and it comes from the side there is a lever on it, open it and let close a few time and see if it stops the leak. It is possible it could stay open and flow even faster. If the leak has not stopped or it comes from one of the tubes on the top and if you feel you are not qualified to repair this get a plumber. In any case the solution would be to either replace the valve or hot water heater. This valve is designed to prevent your hot water tank from exploding in a big ball of steam. It will open if the pressure gets to high or the inside of the top of the tank gets to hot.